SQL JSON помогите пожалуйста
Всем привет, у меня есть таблица в которой есть колонка формата JSON, в ней следующий формат
Таблица название - Payment
Колонка где лежит JSON - Data
{
    "locationId": "111",
    "operatorId": 1111,
    "enteredDate": "2022-03-19T14:02:57.767-05:00",
    "settlements": [
        {
            "type": "Credit Card",
            "amount": 0.01,
            "reference": " "
        },
        {
            "type": "Credit Card",
            "amount": 1284.87,
            "reference": "MasterCard 1256"
        }
    ],
    "Route": 23
}

Нужно сделать запрос чтобы из этой колонки в которой данные в формате JSON выбрать только те записи где есть setlement запись с "amount": 0.01 потому что такой записи может и не быть


Это некорректный JSON, как минимум это всё должно быть снаружи в фигурных скобках. 2) Что конкретно за SQL? Далеко не все БД умеют работать с JSON.


Я добавил фигурные скобки, PostgreSQL

Ну вот например есть какие-то примеры запросов в ответах: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype

к моему примеру непонятно как использовать

Как минимум вам нужно написать в вопросе, как называется таблица и колонка.

добавил названия, спасибо

Пожалуйста, оформите вопрос в точном соответствии с Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL? особое внимание пунктам 5 и 3.

Под рукой нет PostgreSQL, но должно быть примерно так
SELECT *
FROM Payment
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(Data -> 'settlements') AS settlement
    WHERE (settlement ->> 'amount')::numeric = 0.01
);


спасибо большое, работает
